# adding an array of elements to dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I've a dictionary that is to be parsed to a JSON format.
The dictionary looks like this:

```
{'transportation': {'airplane': {'properties': {'fly': {'type': 'string'}, 'pilot': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'car': {'properties': {'drive': {'type': 'string'}, 'driver': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'boat': {'properties': {'sail': {'type': 'string'}, 'sailer': {'type': 'string'}}}}}
```

I want to add a required object to the dictionary with an array of elements.
Therefore I've a recursive function to look through objects and insert the values at the correct level.

My code looks like this:

```
dataReqProp = (
    ['airplane', 'fly'],
    ['boat', 'sail'],
    ['car', 'driver'],
    ['boat', 'sailer']
)

obj = {'transportation': {'airplane': {'properties': {'fly': {'type': 'string'}, 'pilot': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'car': {'properties': {'drive': {'type': 'string'}, 'driver': {'type': 'string'}}}, 'boat': {'properties': {'sail': {'type': 'string'}, 'sailer': {'type': 'string'}}}}}

def update_required_json(obj, target_key, update_value):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == target_key:
                # obj[key].setdefault(json_type, {}).update(update_value)
                obj[key].update({'required': update_value})
            update_required_json(value, target_key, update_value)

    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for entity in obj:
            update_required_json(entity, target_key, update_value)


for key, prop in dataReqProp:
    new_prop = [prop]
    update_required_json(obj, key, new_prop)
    

print(obj)
```

However it does only add one element to the required object. Boat should have the sailer and sail. What am I overlooking here?

I get the following output:

```
{'transportation': {'airplane': {'properties': {'fly': {'type': 'string'}, 'pilot': {'type': 'string'}}, 'required': [['fly']]}, 'car': {'properties': {'drive': {'type': 'string'}, 'driver': {'type': 'string'}}, 'required': [['driver']]}, 'boat': {'properties': {'sail': {'type': 'string'}, 'sailer': {'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ['sailer']}}}
```

But I expect that below boat the required array is only filled with one element. I expect that "sail" should be there as well.

Comment: What is your expected output? It's not clear form the code

Comment: @Nick I've added more explanation on the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
obj[key].update({'required': update_value})
```

which is overwriting the `required` key when you try to add a second value, not updating it. You can use `setdefault` to work around that:

```py
def update_required_json(obj, target_key, update_value):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == target_key:
                obj[key].setdefault('required', []).extend(update_value)
            update_required_json(value, target_key, update_value)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for entity in obj:
            update_required_json(entity, target_key, update_value)
```

Comment: So it was overwriting indeed. This resolved my issue, thanks!